# reCaptcha от Google не отображается

Tags: recaptcha

Зарегистрирован на reCaptcha. Код капчи вставлен в первую форму на странице. Отображается капча корректно и отлично работает. Вставляю этот же код с внутренним ключом на этой же странице в другую форму - не отображается. Во всех последующих формах на этой странице при расположении кода в формах, капча не отображается.В чем может быть проблема? Возможно, на каждую форму отдельная капча? Прошу помощи.

Comment: Каждую капчу через `grecaptcha.render()` запускаете?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало через `grecaptcha.render()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это перед `/body`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Формы:

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
 ...
<div id="recaptcha1"></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
...
<form action="?" method="POST">
...
<div id="recaptcha2"></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var onloadCallback = function() {
mysitekey = 'your_site_key';
grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
'sitekey' : mysitekey
});
grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
'sitekey' : mysitekey    
});
};
</script>
```

Оригинал [здесь](https://kingdom-of-souls.ru/home/programmirovanie/116-dve-ili-bolee-recaptcha-na-odnoj-stranitse)

Все работает!